# Embedded directive not passing its form data to parent controller

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a main form with an embedded form within it. The embedded form changes depending on the type of form the user decides to submit, the outer form remains the same on every case. I'm trying to take both form's content and submit them at the same time. I'm combining the forms on the same model. Outer form: `formHolder.outer...`, Inner form: `formHolder.inner...`

I'm building this on the assumption that a directive within a controller has access to the controller's variables.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MakeRequestCtrl">
    <ng-form name="make_request">
        <template-maker formtype="email"></template-maker>
        <template-maker formtype="email"></template-maker>
        <template-maker formtype="email"></template-maker>

        <input type="text" ng-model="formHolder.outer.fname" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="formHolder.outer.lname" />
        <input type="email" ng-model="formHolder.outer.email" />

        <input type="submit" ng-click="submitForm(formHolder)" value="Submit"/>
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

**Inner Directive**

```
appDirectives.directive('templateMaker', function(){
    return{
        require: '^form',
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            formtype: '@',
            formHolder: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'tp/template_controls.html',
        link: function(scope){
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

**Outer Controller**

```
appControllers.controller("MakeRequestCtrl", function($scope){
    ...
    $scope.returnForm = function(user){
        console.log(user);
    }
    ...
});
```

When I submit the form, and check the console. I only receive the outer form content.

How can I merge the inner form content to the outer form content into my `formHolder` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the `form-holder` attribute to the directive element.

```
<template-maker formtype="email" form-holder="formHolder" ></template-maker>
```

It's also important to remember that camelCase variables in directive scopes are represented with hyphens between change of case, for example `sportsCar` would be `sports-car`.